# Remove the 'xmlns=""' attribute from the 'root' element from XmlWriter/XmlDocument in ASP.NET C# Web Service (asmx)

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-services, xmldocument

I am currently having the following code to generate an XML response for a web service (.asmx) request method.

```
StringWriter stringwriter = new StringWriter();
        XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stringwriter);
        xmlTextWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        xmlTextWriter.WriteStartDocument();
        xmlTextWriter.WriteStartElement("root");
        xmlTextWriter.WriteElementString("Value", demo.Value);
        xmlTextWriter.WriteElementString("ID", demo.ID);
        xmlTextWriter.WriteElementString("CoreProductCode", demo.CoreProductCode);
        xmlTextWriter.WriteEndElement();
        xmlTextWriter.WriteEndDocument();
       XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
           xmlDoc.LoadXml(stringwriter.ToString());
 return xmlDoc;
```

As you can see, there is a 'root' tag which is the starting tag. Now the issue is that it is default accompanied by a  **xmlns=""** attribute with it. So basically, the final response looks like this :

```
<requestProductResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
        <requestProductResult>
            <root xmlns="">
                <Value>0</Value>
                <ID>11</ID>
                <CoreProductCode>1</CoreProductCode>
            </root>
        </requestTokenResult>
```

Now my requirement is such that only **one xmlns attribute is to be allowed** and I am having two of them. So I have to **get rid of the xmlns or the whole root tag.**

Things I have tried :

1. Tried all the 3 method overloads for WriteStartElement(). None of them fit the requirement.
2. Tried setting the NamespaceHandling attribute for the XmlWriter object but didn't work. (I could've used it wrongly).
3. Also tried removing the root element but it showed error.

It would be helpful if you can provide me some more insight on how this can be done and what steps are to be taken. Any sort of guidance and help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Any reason you're using `XmlTextWriter` directly rather than using the simpler `XDocument` API? Fundamentally, you need to write all your elements in the namespace - currently your `requestProductResult` element is in the `"http://tempuri.org/"` namespace, whereas `root` etc aren't. You *could* just include `"http://tempuri.org/"` as a second argument to each of your `WriteStartElement` etc calls...

Comment: I'd second Jon's comment - why not use `XDocument`? I'd also add that your example doesn't completely demonstrate the problem. Where's the part where you add this XML to the `requestProductResponse` document?

Comment: @JonSkeet - This is an older service developed way back. And we're still continuing with this for now. And yes, you are correct in your saying that all the elements should be written under the namespace. But that will still make `"http://tempuri.org/"` appear with the `root`. And `root'` has to be void of any attributes.

Comment: @MattMurdock not seeing any edit? Ideally we need a [mcve] that can just be copy/pasted and run.

Comment: @CharlesMager - Done.

Comment: @MattMurdock not really. It's the adding of this document to the other document that's causing your issue, and you're not showing that. Jon's comment re setting the correct namespace is a good start, but you claim that adds another attribute when combined. We can't see how that is occuring without the code to demonstrate it..